# sql min date with respect to another column

Tags: sql, teradata

I have this situation: 2 columns

```
score   date
-1      09/02/2018
-1      08/02/2018
-1      07/02/2018
 2      06/02/2018
 2      05/02/2018
 2      04/02/2018
-1      02/02/2018
-1      01/02/2018
```

how can I get the min date of the last time the score was `-1`?
I need to get the date: `07/02/2018`

Comment: Surely the minimum date is 01/02/2018 with a score of -1??

Comment: min date of the last time the score was -1 is 01/02/2018. How u get  07/02/2018?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns the oldest date of the most recent series of -1 in your data:

```
SELECT Max(dt)
FROM
 ( -- find all the rows starting a new series of -1
   SELECT datecol as dt, 
      Min(score) -- score of previous date
      Over (ORDER BY datecol DESC
            ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following AND 1 Following) AS prev_score
   FROM tab  
   QUALIFY score = -1                               -- current score must be -1 
       AND (prev_score <> -1 OR prev_score IS NULL) -- and previous score either <> -1 or NULL (data starts with -1)
 ) AS dt
```

You might add PARTITION BY and GROUP BY if you got multiple groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using:

```
select min(t.date)
from t
where t.score = -1 and
      t.date > (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.score <> -1);
```

Comment: it is incorrect if you have last row data is positive

Comment: it is incorrect if you have greater date which have positive score (10/02/2018)

Comment: @RaminDarvishov . . . My interpretation of what the OP needs (which I think is ambiguous) is that `NULL` is acceptable in this case.  The OP can clarify.